# Textarea placeholder not showing up

Tags: html, textarea, placeholder

I have a problem with placeholder text not showing up in the comments block of this code. The form is pretty basic, and is setup in a table like the code below. Placeholder works for all other elements in form like the phone in the example below. Could somebody please key me in on what I am doing wrong?

```html
 <td valign="top">
 
  <input  type="text" placeholder="555-555-5555" name="telephone" maxlength="30" size="30">
 
 </td>
 
</tr>
 
<tr>
 
 <td valign="top">
 
  <label for="comments">Comments *</label>
 
 </td>
 
 <td valign="top">
 
  <textarea placeholder="text"  name="comments" maxlength="1000" cols="25" rows="6" >  </textarea>
 
 </td>
```

Comment: Whitespace inside a textarea counts as content; remove the spaces and it'll work fine.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try deleting the whitespaces:

```
<textarea placeholder="text" name="comments" maxlength="1000" cols="25" rows="6"></textarea>
```

Comment: Thank you much. I guess knowledge is power. Worked like a charm.

Comment: Yes, I also used to remove whitespace when I face with this problem. I dont know why It is taking care of whitespaces while other html elements not caring about?.