# How do I set placeholder for <textarea>?

Tags: html

I am unable to set my placeholder attribute for textarea tag.
What did I do wrong?

```
   <textarea name="eduinfo" id="eduinfo" cols=100% rows="10" placeholder="Write about your academic result
        eg. Math A , Science A, BM and etc (Please provide mininum subjects )"> </textarea>
        </div>
```

I am trying to use placeholder fpr textarea.

Comment: Maybe delete the space between `>` and `</textarea>`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29761335/21754828

Comment: @TheCoder-orratherACoder Not quietly right for this code. The problem is with the incorrect usage of `cols` attribute as per stated in my answer.

Comment: @str1ng try it with `cols=100%` without the quotes, it should still work.

Comment: @TheCoder-orratherACoder Sometimes it will work, sometimes it won't. Depends on a browser and how browser figures it out, but it will definitely get wanted output if you follow standards. Generally said using a percentage as value for the `cols` attribute isn't valid HTML syntax.  If it is specified, it must be a positive integer. If it is not specified, the default value is 20. So, it's more about standard of HTML syntax here.

Comment: @str1ng yeah, I guess... All I said was that deleting the space will fix it. :)

Comment: @TheCoder-orratherACoder And all I said that it's not valid HTML :)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with your `cols` attribute, the way you're using it is not correct.

Instead of setting it by `cols=100%` you should do it by `cols="100"`. Placeholder should be working after this.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
</head>

<body>
  <textarea name="eduinfo" id="eduinfo" cols="100" rows="10" placeholder="Write about your academic result
eg. Math A, Science A, BM, etc. (Please provide minimum subjects)"></textarea>


</body>

</html>
```

***The size of a textarea can also be set by the CSS height and width properties.***

Comment: Thanks....  the solution is so easy. Have a nice day. This thread is closed

Comment: Note that the [<meta>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/semantics.html#the-meta-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification.

Comment: @Rob That's true - `<meta>` tag doesn't require/is never used together with `/`. To elaborate, putting `/` before tag's `>` is known as a self-closing or void tag. However, I still can see it being used with certain HTML elements that do not require a closing tag,such as `<br>`, `<img>`, and `<input>`. The purpose - providing a backward compatibility with XHTML. You can see it being used in MDN - [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Multimedia_and_embedding/Images_in_HTML) .This is more thing of habit in my case - my point <meta> doesn't require a closing tag so I use it.

Comment: No. From the W3C: [Trailing slashes in void-element start tags do not mark the start tags as self-closing](https://github.com/validator/validator/wiki/Markup-%C2%BB-Void-elements#trailing-slashes-in-void-element-start-tags-do-not-mark-the-start-tags-as-self-closing)

Comment: Your HTML is not backwards compatible with XHTML. And it would need to be XHTML or not. You can't have both.

Comment: You see it on the MDN site but that is a bug (how it works) in their editor (prettier) that they can't get out of. There's long commentary on their github page but I can't find the link at the moment.

Comment: [Here's the link](https://github.com/orgs/mdn/discussions/242#discussioncomment-3752163) Note the final comment about Prettier

Comment: In fact, [trailing slashes can cause harm](https://github.com/validator/validator/wiki/Markup-%C2%BB-Void-elements#trailing-slashes-directly-preceded-by-unquoted-attribute-values)

Comment: So don't use the closing slash. In HTML, it has no meaning, it does nothing and browsers ignore it.